There is a linear subspace of the codimension $m+1$ disjoint from a given projective variety of dimension $m$
Let $X\subset \mathbb CP^n$ be a projective variety of dimension $m$, I am stuck on why there is a linear subspace of the codimension $m+1$ disjoint from $X$.
By this discussion, it seems that we can prove by induction:
If $X$ is with codimension 1, i.e. $m=n-1$, then we can always find a codimension $n$ general linear subspace $L$, i.e. a point away from $X$. Assume that if $X$ is with codimension $k$, there exists a general linear subspace $L$ in $\mathbb P^n$ of codimension $n-k+1$ disjoint from $X$. Now suppose $X$ is with codimension $k+1$, the discussion says that we can prove there is a general linear subspace $L$ in $\mathbb P^n$ of codimension $n-k$ disjoint from $X$ "simply by projecting from a point, not in $X$
". I am not sure what it means. Could you please explain more about it? Thanks in advance!

Let $X$ be a $m$-dimensional subvariety of $\mathbb P^n$. By applynig a projective transformation we may assume $X$ does not contain the point $p=[0:\cdots:0:1]$. There is a map
$$f\colon \mathbb P^n\backslash\{p\}\to \mathbb P^{n-1}$$
which sends $[x_0:\cdots:x_n]$ to $[x_0:\cdots:x_{n-1}]$, which is well-defined since one of $x_0,\dots,x_{n-1}$ is not zero.
Now look at the image $f(X)\subset \mathbb P^{n-1}$. I claim $\dim f(X)=\dim X$. Indeed, to prove this it suffices to prove that the morphism $X\to f(X)$ has finite fibers. The fiber is exactly the intersection of a line $L$ in $\mathbb P^n$ going through $p$ and $X$. But this is a Zariski closed subset of $L\simeq\mathbb P^1$  which is not the entire set (since $p\notin L\cap X$) so $L\cap X$ is a finite set.
Now $f(X)$ has smaller codimension than $X$, so by our inductive hypothesis there is a linear subspace $H\subset\mathbb P^{n-1}$ of codimension $m+1$ disjoint from $f(X)$. Now simply take the closure of the pre-image $\overline{f^{-1}(H)}=f^{-1}(H)\cup\{p\}$, which is a linear subspace of $\mathbb P^n$ of codimension $m+1$ disjoint from $X$.
